# Raspberry Pi Zero W, internet ok, but can't ping or SSH into RPI remotely

Tags: wifi

I have a RPI Zero W. I've gone through the process of downloading NOOBS, copying it onto the Pi and installing Raspian.

I can login to the RPI which is connected via WIFI to my home network. I can see it has been assigned an IP address by my router 198.168.0.18, this shows as wlan0 under 'ifconfig', and the routers web interface also shows the IP address assigned.

I've enabled SSH on the RPI using the raspi-config tool.

The problem I'm having is that although the RPI is connected to my network and has internet access, I am unable to access it from another machine on my network via SSH. I simply get 'Connection timed out'. I have no problem connecting to other RPI devices on the network. I am also unable to ping the RPI.

Here's the contents of /etc/network/interfaces

source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
wireless-power off
```

Here is the results of 'ifconfig';

```
lo          Link encap:Local Loopback
            inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
            inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
            UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  METRIC:1
            RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
            TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
            collissions:0 txqueuelen:1
            RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr  b8:27:eb:54:8e:01
            inet addr:192.168.0.18  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
            inet6 addr: fe80::ac07:31d7:dbd7:52fc/64 Scope:Link
            UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
            RX packets:64 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
            TX packets:78 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
            collissions:0 txqueuelen:1000
            RX bytes:0 (10.1 Kib)  TX bytes:11542 (11.2KiB)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try removing this line: wireless-power off from your /etc/network/interfaces.d file

Comment: Could be a firewall issue — what machine do you ping your Pi from? Windows or Linux? Also can your Pi ping the other machine?

Comment: Steve Robillard, the problem existed before I added that line I'm afraid. I added that line in an attempt to resolve the issue.

Comment: Nasha, I'm trying to connect from a Mac, I am able to reach other RPI's on the same Mac though. Yes, the RPI is able to ping other machines on my network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I found the problem. My terminal was already SSH'd into another server which isn't on my local network.

I can't believe I've struggled all afternoon with this.

Comment: Please accept your answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again and again after years.